# How to return related objects a queryset's values_list instead of just the PKs

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to neatly return a queryset's values_list of related objects from many objects' related managers at the same time without having to write a loop ?

In other words this query:

```
Hospital.objects.first().treatments.all().values_list('treatment_appointments', flat=True)
```

will return me a list of PKs that will look something like this:

```
<QuerySet [1, 32, 35, 21, 30, 28, 29, 13, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 66, 67, 87]>
```

Is it possible to write such query that will return the actual objects instead of those PKs?

here are the models:

```
class Treatment(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()

class Hospital(models.Model):
    treatments = models.ManyToManyField(Treatment, related_name='treatments')
    

class Appointment(models.Model):
    treatment = models.ForeignKey(Treatment, related_name='appointment_treatments')
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question upon your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
hospital = Hospital.objects.first()
Appointment.objects.filter(treament__hispital=hospital)
```